# Cannot generate signed apk in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

Some time ago I successfully publish app to Google Play. Now when i tried to publish update for this application, but I cannot generate signed apk. It shows "cannot recover key" but all 2 keys and alias was right. How can I fix this?

The first time application was published by same pc, but before re-installation os.

Comment: Sounds like you lost your key store.  Deactivate the app and republish with new key maybe...

Comment: How could i lost key store if it was in same directory? Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

(windows)

Android Studio>Build>Generate Signed Bundle or APK>Create new...

Just build a new one

Comment: if you signed with new key you cannot update existing app in Google Play.